# How to geospatial cluster FeatureCollection of polygons in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do you geospatial cluster a FeatureCollection of polygons in Google Earth Engine? For example, the FeatureCollection `fc` consists of polygons.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('GLIMS/current')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('geog_area', 'French Alps'))

Map.addLayer(fc, {},'unclustered', false)
Map.centerObject(fc, 7)
```

In other words, I want each polygons to have an additional property 'cluster' which can be used to group geospatially close polygons.

Answer (score 2):

I calculated the centroid longitude and latitude of each polygon. Then I used k-means clustering to cluster the Feature Collection based on these properties.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('GLIMS/current')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('geog_area', 'French Alps'))

Map.addLayer(fc, {},'unclustered', false)
Map.centerObject(fc, 7)

// Get centroids, set centroid Lon and Lat as seperate properties
fc = fc.map(function(f){
  var centroid = f.geometry().centroid()
  return f.set('centroidLon', centroid.coordinates().get(0))
          .set('centroidLat', centroid.coordinates().get(1))
})

var nClusts = 3
// Train the clusterer, using the same data ('fc')
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(nClusts).train(fc, ['centroidLat','centroidLon'])
// Run the clustering algorithm. 
var clustered = fc.cluster(clusterer)

// Display the clusters with random colors.
var empty = ee.Image().byte();
var fills = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: clustered,
  color: 'cluster',
});
var palette = ['FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF'];
Map.addLayer(fills, {palette: palette, max: 2}, 'clusters');
```